# The function "step into my code" in Pycharm

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

In the debug mode in Pycharm, when I click "step into my code", it doesn't step into the function or next line while it immediately runs all the program left and ends automatically. (under Windows 10)

But the same code in Ubuntu 16.04, it doesn't have the problem, and the "step into my code" works perfectly.
I've reinstalled the pycharm but couldn't fix this issue. Are there any reason that causes the problem in Windows 10?  Thank you.

Comment: What kind of code raise this problem? Have you written it, or is it from another package?

Comment: Umm... I think it's not the code's problem because whatever the code I write, the problem still exists.

Comment: Can you assure to use the same combination of buttons both in Ubuntu and Win10? Have you tried clicking "step into my code" alternative buttons (i.e. from top menus).

Comment: yeah, I'd tried both ways, so I don't know what reason can cause that. And I found that the "smart step into"(maybe) also has the same issue.

Comment: That's strange, I use PyCharm both in win10 and Ubuntu and I have never had problem in the debug. Maybe post some image (breakpoints, the button you press to step into, etc.). Also take a look at the PyCharm docs. Try with older version of PyCharm. If you are absolutely sure there is bug in PyCharm just notify the company.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I think that maybe I use pycharm in Ubuntu is better, ha ha :)

Comment: oh, my GOD!!!
It suddenly works perfectly!!! The problem was solved!!!